Node.js Retrieve Electrum Segwit address for Electrum Menemonic
I'm trying to make a little code for get address from a menemonic (Electrum) using node.js.
I created a standard wallet with electrum 4.5.3. The first address in the list is bc1qqv4yzu690ue3tpxjuem0urt3qen90rrpwsh8vj.
Now I want to get this address from the mnemonic phrase using Node.js. This is the code I used:
const bitcoin = require('bitcoinjs-lib');
const bip39 = require('bip39');

// My mnemonic
const mnemonic = 'Electrum Mnemonic';

// Derivation
const seed = bip39.mnemonicToSeedSync(mnemonic);
const root = bitcoin.bip32.fromSeed(seed);

// Derivation of wallet
const path = "m/0/0"; // obtained fro Address info in electrum
const child = root.derivePath(path);

// Make couple of key
const keyPair = bitcoin.ECPair.fromPrivateKey(child.privateKey);
const { address } = bitcoin.payments.p2wpkh({ pubkey: keyPair.publicKey });

console.log('the address is:', address);

The problem is that I receive a different address from the one I have in electrum. I also tried using various derivation patches but to no avail. I'm trying to create a small script to avoid importing the mnemonic phrase into electrum every time.
